# How to dynamically set TValue property of InputNumber component

Tags: dynamic, blazor, tvalue

We can assign and re-use the TValue with help of typeparam in the Blazor platform. But, how will we assign the TValue dynamically for Blazor InputNumber component?

code example:

**[index.razor]**

```
<EditForm>

      @*The below definiton is working*@
      <InputNumber TValue="int?" @bind-Value="@DynamicModelInstance.ValueAsT"></InputNumber>
       @*The below definiton is not working*@
    <InputNumber TValue="DynamicModelInstance.Type" @bind-Value="@DynamicModelInstance.ValueAsT"></InputNumber>
</EditForm>
@code {
    public DynamicModel<int> DynamicModelInstance { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        DynamicModelInstance = new DynamicModel<int>();
        DynamicModelInstance.ValueAsT = 500;
    }
}
```

**[DynamicModel.cs]**

```cs
namespace CustomComponent.Pages
{
public class DynamicModel<T> where T : struct
{
    public System.Type Type { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }

    public DynamicModel()
    {
        this.Type = typeof(T);
    }

    private T _value;

    public T ValueAsT
    {
        get { return (T)_value; }
        set { this._value = value; }
    }
}
}
```

How to achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was your EditForm:

> EditForm requires either a Model parameter, or an EditContext parameter

```
<EditForm Model="dynamicModelInstance">
    <InputNumber @bind-Value="@dynamicModelInstance!.Value" />
</EditForm>
@code {
    public DynamicModel<int>? dynamicModelInstance;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        dynamicModelInstance = new()
        {
            Value = 500
        };
    }
}
```

```
public class DynamicModel<T> where T : struct
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Even though we specified Modal or EditContext i could not specify the TValue dynamically. It shows the below error.


The type or namespace name 'type/namespace' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)